Visual Studio Code displaying "..." instead of the output in .iypnb files
When running code in cells of a .iypnb file in VisualStudioCode I often encounter the issue of VSC not showing any output, but rather just three gray dots:

Pressing on said dots gives two options:

If I copy the output and paste it somewhere, I do indeed get 'Anything' (or whatever the output was supposed to be) i.e. the output is there, it's just not visible. Reloading VSC can solve the issue, but it's rather tiring and I was wondering if there is a way to make it stop.

Those dots are always there when a cell has output, so it's not "instead". What's actually happening is that the output isn't showing at all, or in other words, isn't being rendered. You can [edit] to clarify that. Why it's happening though, IDK.

Is there anything abnormal in the Jupyter output and Python output?the logs inside them could help resolve the issue.
